# How to embed a timechart visualization from a Splunk query into a web app?

Tags: iframe, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I have the following Splunk query that produces the following visualization:

[image]

I would like to embed this exact visualization into a web app using an iframe. How can I do this?

Currently, I am using the Splunk HTTP REST API and can submit & get the results back from this search using the following endpoint:
`/servicesNS/nameofmyapp/nameofmynamespace/search/jobs/1535641234.45678?output_mode=json`

However, I would like a src URL to the visualization that can be embedded in an iframe. Is there an endpoint that I can query instead that will give the URL to the visualization?

Comment: Embedded scheduled reports is how you want to do that. See http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Report/Embedscheduledreports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save it as a report first. like the comment above, here's some documentation:
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Report/Embedscheduledreports